# How to direct user to the contents and not the properties after clicking lookup field pointing to folder in WSS?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, wss, wss-3.0

**Background**

I want to put a lookup field in sharepoint list that will point to a folder. Thats the easy part, but I want user to be pointed to folder contents (not the folder properties) after clicking on the link. It's not possible from the sharepoint interface so I'm trying to create custom field type.

**Question**
What method should I overload in SPFieldLookup derived class (or anywhere else :P) to be able to point user to folder contents?

P.S. Please don't suggest creating a hyperlink field cause the link will break under different access mappings.

Comment: I have solved the issue. I was trying to create a cannon to kill a fly. Now I'm using url field (using relative url). I'm still curious though what is controling the url created by lookup field.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a custom field, I would consider a computed field (search for "computed" [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/HA102390461033.aspx)) and keep your current lookup field.  The computed field is simply a UI representation of a column.  That is how SharePoint does Title, Title with link, Title with menu, etc.  Those aren't multiple columns, just multiple ways to view the same data.

To use this approach you need to be able to build your link from the data available to you.  We have done this using custom RESTful web services when the data is not immediately available.